# Apache: how to hide server version and operation system from users?

Tags: apache, apache2

I've read on one site that I need to add two lines to `httpd.conf` file:

> ServerSignature Off
>
> ServerTokens Prod

But when I've added them nothing changed. As previously I can see in my browser

> Apache/2.2.16 (Debian)

Maybe that's important: When I opened file (I mean before adding above lines) `httpd.conf` I saw it's empty. I use VPS.

Thanks!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

you didnt give enough information about os/distribution etc

but in ubuntu's apache installation apache2.conf looks like this:

```
<cut>
Include httpd.conf
Include ports.conf
Include conf.d/
Include sites-enabled/
```

and in *conf.d/security* you can see

```
ServerTokens OS
```

just check your configs, somewhere it gets overwritten after you set it in your httpd.conf

Comment: Yes, I found they overriden in `security` file. When I've changed them there - apache version and OS information dissappered. Thanks!

Comment: Can we hide the server name itself? i.e., `Apache`

Answer (score 49):

Simple:

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/security.conf
```

Then:

- change `ServerTokens OS` to `ServerTokens Prod`
- change `ServerSignature On` to `ServerSignature Off`

Restart Apache :

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

This article may also help you: [Hide Apache Information](http://digitalsoft.in/hide-apache-information-on-ubuntu-vps-dedicated-web-server/)

Comment: This worked perfectly to me. Wondering why isn't it the default on Apache.

Comment: Doesn't work on Windows :( Still shows "Server: Apache/2.4.43 (Win64)"

Comment: did not work for me on ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 3):

To [also hide the name "Apache"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26296886/completely-hide-server-name-apache#26300136):

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-security2
```

Then add this to `/etc/apache2/apache.conf` (you can use any name, here I've used space):

```
<IfModule security2_module>
    SecRuleEngine on
    ServerTokens Min
    SecServerSignature " "
</IfModule>
```

and restart Apache:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

For a full write up incorporating the answer by @ShanuTThankachan see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65883445/1741690).

Comment: did not work for me