# Completely hide server name apache

Tags: apache, debian, apache-config

I have added these 2 lines in my etc/apache2.conf file, and it hid the OS and apache version.

```
ServerSignature Off
ServerTokens Prod
```

But after all I can see the header with server name

```
Server  Apache
```

How to hide this information as well ?
I am using Debian 7, apache v 2.2

Thanks

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Apache on its own cannot completely unset the Server header (not even with mod_headers).

This [appears to be by design](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=40026), as discussed by the Apache devs.

There is a way to do this using ModSecurity, but I know little about that. Instead, these people have it all figured out already:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124137/change-apache-httpd-server-http-header

I can verify that this works, just tried on Debian 7.6.

**edit:**
install mod security for apache and then add this in your `apache2.conf`.

```
<IfModule security2_module>
    SecRuleEngine on
    ServerTokens Full
    SecServerSignature " "
</IfModule>
```

After this restarting the apache, Server header will disappear

Comment: thanks man, that worked !!, i justed edited your answer and included that code snippet.

Comment: After searching for several hours, this is the one solution that seemed to work. Thanks!

Comment: By setting `ServerTokens Min` I was also able to remove the loaded modules (e.g. `mod_fastcgi`) from the header response that appeared after the blank server name.

Comment: @SharpC thanks for your answer. I solved my mod_fastcgi problem with Min option.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work on `https` if `ServerTokens` set to `prod`, but it works fine on `http`. With `Full`  or `Min` it works on both `http` and `https`...go figure

Answer (score 8):

[Apache Security - Ivan Ristić | Chapter 2.3 Changing Web Server Identity](https://www.feistyduck.com/library/apache-security/online/apachesc-CHP-2.html)

To confuse the hacker and guess what Linux OS or what version of Apache he is using.
You can change the Apache server name to whatever you want.

For ubuntu 20.04:

### Apache default configuration:

`$ sudo apt install apache2 -y`

`$ curl -I localhost`

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 23 Oct 2020 01:31:44 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu)
```

### Change the Apache server name to whatever you want:

`$ sudo apt install libapache2-mod-security2`

`$ sudo a2enmod security2`

`$ sudo vim /etc/apache2/conf-available/security.conf`

ServerTokens Full

ServerSignature Off

SecServerSignature Microsoft-IIS/10.0

`$ sudo systemctl restart apache2`

`$ curl -I localhost`

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 23 Oct 2020 01:54:00 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
```

`$ whatweb http://localhost`

```
HTTPServer[Microsoft-IIS/10.0], IP[127.0.0.1], Microsoft-IIS[10.0]
```

If the SecServerSignature option is set to `SecServerSignature " "`
This completely hides the apache server name.

`$ curl -I localhost`

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 23 Oct 2020 02:39:50 GMT
Server:
```

Answer (score 1):

It's equivalent of adding:

```
SecServerSignature " "
```

To the file: `/etc/apache2/mods-available/security2.conf`

Comment: You lacked to state that the `libapache2-mod-security2` package is needed, your solution prior to installing it left me with a broken Apache instance. But the answer by 'blessed' helped! Thanks anyway.

Comment: @MSBerends I see, thanks for the comment and stating that.