# Remove HTTP header IN PHP

Tags: php, http-headers

i want to remove Server http header in my php project so that The programming language of my project is not recognizable.(i use apache server)

i am try to do this with this topic

```
php.net/manual/en/function.header-remove.php
```

but i can't do that.

plz help me

Comment: The Server header is generally added by the webserver (Apache, Nginx, etc) - which one are you using?

Comment: I use apache web server

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124137/change-apache-httpd-server-http-header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid having the "X-Powered-By: PHP" in your server response header, open up php.ini and change the following line:

```
expose_php = Off
```

Then restart the web server and the header should be gone.

**Note:**

As remarked by Nico Haase, the question has been asked on SO before and a possible solution can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318806/hiding-phps-x-powered-by-header).

Comment: i do this but header is recognizable yet (in mozilla inspector > network tab):     Apache/2.4.27 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2l PHP/7.1.9

Comment: There is an [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26296886/completely-hide-server-name-apache) based on what @iainn commented that seems to do the trick.