# How to unset (Hide) "Server" header in Apache 2.4.39 Apache configuration running on Amazon Linux

Tags: apache, server, header, httpd.conf

I am using Amazon Linux and running Apache 2.4.39.
I have added "Header unset Server" along with "ServerToken Prod" and "ServerSignature Off".

However, I still see "Server: Apache" in the headers.
Further I tried setting Server header to null using below:
Header set Server ""

This works and shows the null header however, it works only for index.php.

I want this to work for all the pages supported by the website like .gif, admin.css etc.

Please suggest!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The [tag:apache] tag that you use points you to a place where httpd-configuration questions are on topic

Answer (score 2):

Try my suggested fix [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35360516/cant-remove-server-apache-header#65883445):

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-security2
```

then add this to the end of `/etc/apache2/apache.conf`:

```
<IfModule security2_module>
    SecRuleEngine on
    ServerTokens Min
    SecServerSignature " "
</IfModule>
```

and restart Apache:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: this definitely worked for me. After trying tons of other approaches this was a lifesaver

Answer (score 1):

Here is my contribution which appends to the file and all in one.

```
curl -skIL localhost
sudo apt-get install -y libapache2-mod-security2
cat >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf << 'EOL'
<IfModule security2_module>
    SecRuleEngine on
    ServerTokens Min
    SecServerSignature " "
</IfModule> 
EOL
sudo service apache2 restart
curl -skIL localhost
```

Example:

```
root@CoolServerName:/home/ubuntu# curl -skIL localhost
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Wed, 09 Nov 2022 18:15:15 GMT
Server: Apache
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
Content-Length: 362
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-
root@CoolServerName:/home/ubuntu# cat >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf << 'EOL'
<IfModule security2_module>
    SecRuleEngine on
    ServerTokens Min
    SecServerSignature " "
</IfModule> 
EOL
root@CoolServerName:/home/ubuntu# sudo service apache2 restart
root@CoolServerName:/home/ubuntu# curl -skIL localhost
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Wed, 09 Nov 2022 18:16:45 GMT
Server:  
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
Content-Length: 362
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

root@CoolServerName:/home/ubuntu#
```